# TemplateNotFound(Error 500) raised while using Flask even though template file exists;jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, flask, deployment, jinja2

I want to implement a machine learning model but i implement flask,i am getting this error template not found even though i have template folder.
I have tried all the possible solution given on stack overflow but nothings works,please help me.
The basic code is to run the index page and even that is not working.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="C:/Users/sweet/Music/Rumor_Detection_Project_Copy/Front_End/templates")
app.debug=False
@app.route('/')

def index():
    with app.app_context(), app.test_request_context():
        template = render_template('C:/Users/sweet/Music/Rumor_Detection_Project_Copy/Front_End/templates/index.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Thing which I have tried are:

- Renaming templates to template
- Using the proper sub-directory
- Debug feature both on and off
- Catch statement for error 500

***PLEASE HELP AS THIS IS THE BASIC AND I HAVE TO DO A LOT OF OTHER THINGS TOO***

[code with error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnMRz.png)

Comment: Can you try `index.html` instead of the full path? `render_template` normally takes the name of the template inside the template folder.

Answer (score 0):

The template should be stored in the same directory as the flask script.It can then be used by passing the name of the html file to the render_template() function.

Also, there should be no blank lines between the decorator(`@app.route('/')`) and the def function.

Your code should look like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    with app.app_context(), app.test_request_context():
        template = render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: It did not work,and the index page is in the same directory inside the template/templates folder and even after removing the line between decorator and def function it is showing the same error